# Web browser that exports bookmarks for Android? Open source / no ads

Tags: android

I was surprised to find out neither Firefox not Chrome on my Android phone have feature to export bookmarks. Web search confirmed they do not have it. Are there any open source (or at least no ads) web browsers working on Android that have export/import bookmarks feature?

Added:

For Firefox web search found e.g. https://support.mozilla.org/ru/questions/1065613

```
 First you have to find browser.db,, using a powerful file explorer like Es File explorer or Z-archiver
The file path is / Device / data / data / org.mozilla.firefox / files / mozilla / xxxxxxxx.default
Then download the free SQLite Database Browser (http://sqlitebrowser.org/) for your laptop
Open browser.db with the soft and export "bookmarks" table to an Excel table
You have to a slight modification in Excel and create .HTML file 
...
You need to have root permission in your device. Without root permission you can't modify or even see system files on Android.
```

I don't have root access, but here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13006315/how-to-access-data-data-folder-in-android-device it is explained how to use `adb` for that. However the backup file size was only ~500 bytes, I assume:

> Note that the backup approach will yield an empty backup if your app has disabled backups via android:allowBackup="false" in the manifest.

Also my `openssl` does not have `zlib` command to extract data via `dd if=backup.ab bs=24 skip=1|openssl zlib -d > backup.tar` from archive created via `adb backup -f \location\on\local\drive -noapk app.package.name`.

So I'm back to original question.